# How do apply Puppet class locally

Tags: docker, puppet, configuration-management, devops

So I have a Puppet configuration that I would like to use to configure Docker
images but I'm not sure how to apply them locally.

My goal is to hopefully do something like:

```
RUN puppet apply -e "roles::database"
```

In my Dockerfile.

For example I might have a manifest that I want to apply that contains 
something like:

```
class roles::database {
    include ::profiles::base
}
```

But when I go:

```
puppet apply -e "roles::database"
```

I get:

```
Could not parse for environment production: Syntax error at end of file at line 1 on node.
```

Could someone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4):

Please check the following [examples](https://docs.puppetlabs.com/references/3.3.1/man/apply.html#EXAMPLE).

First - ensure your module path is set correctly. You can provide `modulepath` as a parameter to `apply`.

Second - `"roles::database"` is not a piece of Puppet code.

Try this:

```
puppet apply -e "include roles::database"
```

or:

```
puppet apply --modulepath=/path_to_modules -e "include roles::database"
```